# C# DataTables from stored procedure using dbContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, datatable

I have a very complex stored procedure that is definitely returning values when I run `ExecuteReader` but when I try to load the data, it seems to disappear.

```
        using (var dbContext = new SuperPortalDbContext())
        {
            // Create resulting data table
            System.Data.DataTable result = new DataTable(); 

            // Create command 
            var cmd = dbContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = commandType;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;

            // Add all parameters
            foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
            {
                var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
                p.ParameterName = parameter.ParameterName;
                p.Value = parameter.Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            }

            try
            {
                // Execute
                dbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
                System.Data.Common.DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                result.Load(reader);
            }
            finally
            {
                // closes the connection
                dbContext.Database.Connection.Close();
            }

            // returns the DataSet
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Is it returning multiple results?  Check `reader.NextResult()` to see.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: No, if I try reader.NextResult() I get an exception. Reader definitely has 18 fields which is correct and also HasRows is true so there is data there. I tried creating using this method                 DataSet dsCustomers = new DataSet();
                dsCustomers.Tables.Add("Customers");
 
                //Load DataReader into the DataTable.
                dsCustomers.Tables[0].Load(sdr);   and managed to get data across, but only one field, this can't be the only way to load the data?

Comment: What exception?  That's unexpected; dd that to your question.  Also run it in SSMS and output to text mode to see exactly what gets returned.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException, I get this if I try to run NextResult() after the Load() so I think the Load() is breaking the reader. Is there a limit on the number of rows this method can handle as I've got 270k.

Comment: There is no row limit.

Comment: Why are you recreating the `SqlParameter`s instead of just adding them to the command's parameter collection as-is? What you're doing there is a partial copy by throwing away the original parameters' properties like `SqlDbType`, `Direction`, `IsNullable`, `Size`, `Precision` and `Scale` (and others) which can't be helping anything.

Comment: Perhaps you need to do "set nocount on" in your procedure. Sometimes it trips out the code